# How to dilsplay all poroduct of a category in home page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How can I display all products in home page in magento. I use this code but home page shows **There are no products matching the selection.**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you actually have any products in the database?

Comment: Yes @Sourabh I have only one product for testing.

Comment: then check the id of that product is 8 or not in database

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"  columnCount="3"}}
```

For more [info](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2012/09/display-product-on-home-page.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in your home CMS page.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Where `category_id` is id of category from which products will be shown.